# React-Native number formatting

Tags: react-native, format

I'm currently using the react-native-globalize library to format numbers but when using:

```
<FormattedNumber value={10000000} useGrouping={true} />
```

Which is supposed to present a result like this:

```
> 10,000,000
```

But for some but reason it doesn't seem to be working at all and the output is the number with no separators.

Anyone knows how to solve this or another library I could use? (yes I have done my google research first).

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this function simply.

```
const numberWithComma = x => {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ',');
  };
```

When you call this function:

```
numberWithComma(10000000)
```

the result should be as follows:

```
10,000,000
```

For example:

```
let val = 14234523;

... ... 

<Text> {numberWithComma(val)} </Text>
```

Result:

```
14,234,523
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method `toLocaleString()` provided by Javascript.

Use it as:

```
getFormattedNumber = number => {
    let formattedNumber = Number.parseInt(number).toLocaleString('en-IN');
    return formattedNumber;
}
```

You may use `en-US` based on your region.

If the above code fails in Android, try below steps:

1. Goto your `android/app/build.gradle` file
2. Change line `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'` to `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`

Above solution is here: https://blog.bam.tech/developer-news/formating-numbers-in-react-native

Comment: Is there one that handles decimals? e.g. `getFormattedNumber(12345.67)` => `12,345.67`.

Answer (score 0):

```
numberFormat = (value) => {
    var re = '\\d(?=(\\d{' + 3 + '})+' + '\\D' + ')';
    var num = value.toFixed(Math.max(0, ~~2));
    var str = num.replace(new RegExp(re, 'g'), '$&' + ',');
    return str;
}
```

Use:

```
numberFormat(4000)
```

Result:

```
4,000.00
```